# "Let's/We let A be a variable"

Tags: word-choice, mathematics

Suppose I am giving a math talk and I am going to write on the board *Let A be a variable*. What do I say while I write? Can I say *Let's let A be a variable* or should I write *We let A be a variable* and say the same thing?

Comment: I think there's a certain amount of "crosstalk" between computer programming languages and spoken English here. Yes, it's perfectly possible to say/write any of OP's alternatives, but they're all a bit "geek speak". I'd either say *Create [or Assume] a variable A*, or more likely *Call the first variable A* (since there are probably going to be others).

Comment: *"Let's let.."* sounds fine to me - I hear math lecturers use it all the time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should simply write and say

> Let A be a variable

and the audience will understand what you are conveying.

> Let us let A be a variable

and

> We let A be a variable

are fine but unnecessarily long.

Comment: In all the cases the audience will understand. I was wondering which one is both correct and helps to engross the audience most.

Answer (score 7):

I'd use "Let A be a variable" in speaking, too.

"Let's let A..." is correct grammatically, but sounds unnatural.

I wouldn't use "Let us A...", it isn't correct.

"We let A be..." is correct, but I insist that the first option is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

*Let's let A ...* is grammatical. *Let us A be*... is not.

Comment: sorry, I meant "We let A be...", not "let us A be". I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Then 'We let A be...' is also grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

You're a teacher.  Communication is possibly more important than correctness.  For this reason, I would use:

> Let *A* be a variable.

Also, this is posed as a command to your students, which is applicable in your situation.

Comment: Why quotes?  In speaking, you would not say the quotes, and in printed mathematical work you would use italics: Let *A* be a variable.

Comment: @GEdgar, because I'm sick and not thinking straight.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I would say `Let x be variable` and I would avoid using `A`.  The reason is that `a` is already an overloaded letter in English and it's not immediately clear whether you are about to introduce a singular noun (e.g., `Let a cat out of the house.`) or the name of a variable.

Another useful phrase would be `Let lambda equal` as it's likely you are about to introduce the definition of a variable.  If you are talking about a variable that's in the middle of an equation, you could just use a declarative: `mu is variable` or `c is constant`.

Comment: I disagree. I think the indefinite article is important, because the OP is defining A. For your examples of mu or c, they are (probably) already defined elsewhere (we all know that c is the speed of light in a vacuum).